# Google Pixel 7/7 Pro : Spontaneous Pictures \ Quick Shutter Mode Experience

Tags: camera, google-pixel

I was curious to know about the **shutter speed** and how *quickly* one can jump into camera mode from lock screen/from-doing-something to capture those spontaneous moments.

Usually what I have noticed on android is that if some large\heavy app\many apps are open it tends to lag and slows you going into camera mode, and get the UI up and capture the picture, by that time that moment passes by.

Also do you know any lags started to creep in when quickly and frequently switching between camera modes (pic\video\portrait\etc) ?

Please share your experience on this for Google Pixel 7 and 7 Pro.

Please also share any YouTube reviews\articles where the experience of taking photos\videos is covered, not the end result

**Note:** Please share this based on a phone you have bought and have been using it as your daily use phone, don't want reviews of demo phones where usually nothing is loaded and its fairly Out-of-box phone.